# Failed to parse source map, showing when running my react app. also it isnot hosting due to this issue?

Tags: reactjs

Failed to parse source map from 'C:\portfolio\prjwlvk\node_modules@mediapipe\tasks-vision\vision_bundle_mjs.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\portfolio\prjwlvk\node_modules@mediapipe\tasks-vision\vision_bundle_mjs.js.map'

while doing npm start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.